# Vertical Nav Menu Wont Show More SubCateogories

Tags: css, menu, navigation, nav

I'm having trouble with css, revealing more than two sub-cateogories under menu header. Please take a look at example here http://thebrlab.com/ugo-mozie/

Answer (score 1):

Line 33 in your stylesheet - `menu.css`.

Change the height on `:hover` from `93px` to `155px;`.

```
.menu-item:hover ul {
    height: 155px;
}
```

Pretty self explanatory.