# Vertical Nav Menu Won't Hover

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, nav

I'm having trouble trying to figure out why via mobile (iPhone, iPad, etc.), the sub-cateogories on my nav menu won't open. I have installed here: http://thebrlab.com/ugo-mozie/index.html Here is the original example demo of the nav menu http://thebrlab.com/ugo-mozie/menu.html (which works well when I tap the headers on mobile)

Comment: I already answered your question yesterday.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204995/vertical-nav-menu-wont-show-more-subcateogories/19205013#19205013

Comment: Josh, I was able to fix the sizing on the hover opening, thank you for that. However, now it's not responding through mobile, the way it does on the demo (as mentioned above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it won't work is because the device can't sense whether you are hovering over it. It only senses when you touch it and it is non-clickable

Seeing as the link goes nowhere remove the href off the a tag and if you want to have a pointing cursor (clickable content) add this css rule:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

This way it will work on mobile and the page won't keep refreshing when you accidentally click it

Comment: Thanks. Why is it that the demo senses it, but my page doesn't? The demo works fine on mobile.

Comment: This is because it uses hash links which don't refresh the page just navigate round it. Please feel free to accept

Comment: Ok I see. Where in my css do I add the cursor pointer rule? Also, if I remove the link from the href a tag, how will I be able to navigate to other pages? I'm sorry.